# PHP: how to convert php file to PDF file

Tags: php, pdf, attachment, phpmailer

i want to send an email with a PDF attachment.but the file is a php file which generated dynamically.so i want to convert the php file into PDF..

i have used phpmailer here.

```
$mail->AddAttachment("view.php");
```

how to convert view.php to a pdf file

Comment: As above question asked many times, but have a look at http://www.tcpdf.org/

Comment: Do you just want to create the file and attach it later with the mailto function or do you want to send the email from your website?  v [swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html) is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout mpdf lib.

[Site](http://mpdf.bpm1.com/index.php?page=Download)

[Examples & Docs](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=286)

Answer (score 0):

Using fPDF or mPDF, You can get the integration tutorial from these websites

http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php

http://www.fpdf.org/